# PHP Curl - Redirect after login

Tags: php, curl

I wanted to get data from a website with curl.
First I login like this:

```
$userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.0.4) Gecko/20060508 Firefox/1.5.0.4"; 

$ch = curl_init("https://192.168.67.10/Appliance/index.jsp"); 

$username="***"; 
$password="***"; 
$submit = "userid=$username&pass=$password&submitted=true&rememberMe=0";

if(!$ch) { 
    die(sprintf("Fehler[%d]: %s", 
        curl_errno($ch), curl_error($ch))); 
} 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookie.txt");  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $submit);

$data = curl_exec($ch); 

if(!$data) { 
    die(sprintf("Fehler [%d]: %s", 
        curl_errno($ch), curl_error($ch))); 

} 

curl_close($ch); 

echo $data;
```

How can I access another page now?

Login page: `https://192.168.67.10/Appliance/HomePage/index.jsp`
Page I want to access: `https://192.168.67.10/Appliance/SystemsCenter/Encryption/CertificateStore/index.jsp`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!$data){
    //your existing code

}else{
    //it was successful
    curl_close($ch);
    //repeat process of instantiating curl here
}
```

Comment: I want to get data from the second page, not a redirect to it ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I alrdy tried this, but I just get the login page again?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see you using `CURLOPT_POST`. So please add this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

Also, use enable follow redirect, so that no stone keep unturned!

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

Comment: Hey Sabuj,thanks for your answer. The Login is working. If I use Followlocation, 1 in my first curl request, I will be redirected to 'http://192.168.111.131/Appliance/HomePage/index.jsp' which doesn't help me.